# ET1 Enterprise Tablet Motorola Emulator Android

Tags: android, emulation, motorola

Does anyone know if there exists an emulator for the ET1 Enterprise tablets from Motorola? I am currently in need of one, since I need to work on an app.

As far as I can see in the Android-sdk manager there is none available.

Thanks 
Rajat

Answer (score 0):

ET1 uses version 2.3.4. I don't think you need an specific emulator, just SDK environment to lunch a virtual machine with that version.